# Should we guess an answer, with an educational purpose to help novice programmers?

Tags: discussion, answers

During the process of making the questioner of this question, [nested-div-styling-offset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43658219/nested-div-styling-offset), aware of that the code didn't reproduce the problem, **an answer was posted**, which I found more of a guess.

After a dialog with the *answerer*, where I stated my point of view in this, to not answer questions until it's answerable, the *answerer* mean that the outcome is positive to post *guess-like* answers anyway, as it helps novice programmers.

My question is: *Is that something we should do and encourage others to do?*

Please take the time to read the comments made on the answer.

Comment: @gnat No, can't see how that is a duplicate. I am asking about one of the question's given answer's, not how long to wait before vote to close

Comment: preventing guessing answers is a purpose of closing. As pointed in the top answer over there you wait zero seconds before closing unclear questions (prevention applies to your own answers just like to anybody else's)

Comment: @gnat I rephrased my question to make it more clear. Hope you now can see it is not a duplicate, still, I got my answer to this whether is stays a dupe or not.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No, we don't want people posting wild guesses as answers to unclear questions.  That's *why unclear questions get closed in the first place*.  If we didn't want to stop people from posting low quality answers to unanswerable questions then there wouldn't be a need to close them in the first place.

Comment: So you're saying that's where we need to draw the line. When you're not able to reproduce the issue here, you're not worthy of our time and help. Is this correct?

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu It's not that they're not worthy of time or help, rather, the question *cannot be answered* and as such the author needs to improve the question *so that it is answerable* before we can answer it.  People are of course more than welcome to assist the author in improving the question such that it becomes answerable (although they are of course not *obligated* to do so; it is the author's responsibility to ensure the question is improved, no one else's).