# Why do we close rant meta posts at all?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

Sometimes, meta posts where OP behave "irrationally" gets closed as "not seeking discussions".

**What's the purpose of such closures?**

- Before or after the closure, it remains possible to discuss... through the comment. Except that it's terribly hard to read and format properly, no proper voting system, as well as the 600 character limit of comments.
- To inform the OP that they should not ask such questions? It's possible to just do that in comments.

And...

- If the actual issue has been discussed before in meta, it's simpler to just close as duplicate.
- Otherwise, it might be a *new, actual* issue that deserves an answer. Even though it may not help the OP,
  it will help future visitors (if they can find the question at all... meta is hard to search),
  **and** someone might post a different answer that the OP accepts.

---

Related questions~

- [Is "does not appear to seek input and discussion" applicable because of comments?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300183/is-does-not-appear-to-seek-input-and-discussion-applicable-because-of-comments)
  [Can we update the "rant" close reason to link to how to *constructively* conduct criticisms of Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/268226/can-we-update-the-rant-close-reason-to-link-to-how-to-constructively-conduct?noredirect=1&lq=1)
  [Can we slow down on the deletes on Meta, folks?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/405585/can-we-slow-down-on-the-deletes-on-meta-folks)
- [Why does meta have a downvote option at all](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274635/why-does-meta-have-a-downvote-option-at-all)
  [Why do we vote on meta posts? Measuring community feeling?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/387332/why-do-we-vote-on-meta-posts-measuring-community-feeling)

---

Remark: this meta question comes from this specific meta question

["A moderator has deleted this post and it cannot be undeleted", and flag afterwards was refused as well](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/413687/a-moderator-has-deleted-this-post-and-it-cannot-be-undeleted-and-flag-afterwa)

To explain on [my comment there](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/413687/a-moderator-has-deleted-this-post-and-it-cannot-be-undeleted-and-flag-afterwa?noredirect=1#comment884111_413687)
(and also "what I could post as an answer"):

> In that case *(only) I think* that none of the correctly addresses the issue (not really their fault, OP didn't explain the situation clearly either). The actual issue is
>
> - The error is very generic (server is not running / the executable is not found) and the answer depends a lot on the environment
> - Without specific details on the environment, answerers can only guess.
> - These questions are highly popular, so it doesn't seem like a good idea to just close them, like what meta questions linked below suggests.
>
> Then
>
> - Someone get that error message, and several other error messages.
> - By trial and error (that took them a few hours), they figured out a solution that is not included in any existing answers.
> - They're not quite sure whether that solution applies to the specific question, because of the reason explained above.
> - They can't make the answer question-specific, because they don't know *why* the answer works (nor they understand the root cause of the issue), only that it seems to work in their particular case.
>
> Surely the policy of not posting duplicate answer makes sense, and mods aren't necessarily subject expert.
>
> But it's true that in this case having the answer somehow on the page will help (a bit...) *some* particular future users.
>
> - What would be the best thing to happen?
>
>   Some subject expert posts a comprehensive answer that explains *(almost)* every possible causes that may create the issue, and how to diagnose the issue.
> - What could the user do?
>
>   In my opinion, posting one answer and leave comments like "Same error, different cause, see also [other_question]" on the others is the best way.
>
> Reference:
>
> - [Should we guess an answer, with an educational purpose to help novice programmers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/348494/should-we-guess-an-answer-with-an-educational-purpose-to-help-novice-programmer)
>   [Can I answer if I'm not sure?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/370133/can-i-answer-if-im-not-sure)
>   [Posting a suggestion when I'm not sure about the answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/281010/posting-a-suggestion-when-im-not-sure-about-the-answer)

Comment: Thinking about it... another purpose could be "signal to other users that they should not answer this question", but then isn't that what downvote for already?

Comment: *"it's simpler to just close as duplicate."* -  That often is what happens. In the case of the *"does not appear to seek input and discussion"* close reason, that doesn't necessarily apply to the question, but can also apply to the user. If the user has posted a reasonable question, but the isn't receptive then while the question might (as written) be looking for input, the user is in fact only looking for validation or an echo chamber, and not input or discussion.

Comment: @Nick (also as explained in the question) but what about future users come across the question? Just write a neutral answer and post it to the question instead.

Comment: That's honestly a waste of key presses. The questions that (generally) get closed for that reason have been asked dozens of times before, and the duplicates are _very_ easy to find. Adding more of them is of no benefit.

Comment: @Nick There seems to be some kind of circular logic here. If duplicates are very easy to find, just close as duplicate instead.

Comment: Duplicates should still be useful. The ones in question are not, in fact they're often actively harmful, hence they get closed and deleted.

Comment: Also I'm looking for some explanation for this particular case what the user should have done. Is my note above okay?

Comment: My guess is that whole issue came up due to the system finding significant parts of the answers that were identical and that's how the mod got involved in the deletion(s). I agree with your suggestion of leaving comments pointed at one answer. Unfortunately that discussion didn't go well since the OP of that meta post pretty much dug in and simply wanted to be right and get their way without being flexible to such alternate solutions

Comment: @user202729 I think closing that particular question as a duplicate of [Why was my answer deleted by a moderator for being a duplicate?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/402635/why-was-my-answer-deleted-by-a-moderator-for-being-a-duplicate) would've made more sense than the reason given. It's not particularly ranty, although they also weren't very responsive.

Comment: @Nick Hm, reading that question, it's one with the same error message but completely different cause (the cause of *that* question is OP accidentally post wrong answer text instead, after edit still get delete), and okay suggestions to this (new) question (post comment to link) can't be applied to that answer either (because the questions are unrelated)

Comment: What resulted in the response (making a mistake with copying vs reposting the same answer in multiple places) is IMO, irrelevant. The result is the same, the same answer was posted in multiple places, and the fix is the same, ask moderators to delete all but the best one (which the use can choose themselves) and flag the other posts as duplicates of the one with the undeleted answer. Duplicates are generally based on _answers_, not questions. Hence the close banner says "This question _already has answers_ here", and not "This question has been asked before"

Comment: @Nick No, the fix is different. In this case the best course of action is to leave "related questions:" comments (they're not duplicate, as far as I can see, or at least nobody can tell whether they're or they're not because of the environment issue), in *that* case is to explain to the mod that the answers are different and undelete *both*.

Comment: Actually... in this case I *could* write a generic answer to *that* question that addresses all the cases and close the other questions as duplicate of that one instead.

Comment: @user202729 Indeed you could. The generic solutions are often the best solutions and make the best duplicate targets (although it is possible to be _too_ generic).

Comment: I was talking about a (more) generic answer to the meta question, but okay.

Comment: Damned if you close rant questions, [damned if you do not](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/405665).

Comment: It's human nature. If there is an uncontrolled fire, people will want to throw water on it to put it out.

Comment: @Gimby And the people not throwing water on it are staying as far away from it as they can.

Comment: @Nick ha ha :) Not really true on meta, isn't it though? Rant posts draw in SO many comments which do little more than aggravate the situation. It's irresistible.

Comment: @Nick _And the people not throwing water on it are staying as far away from it as they can._ From my experience as a fireman I can assure you, they *don't* stay away.

Comment: Looking at my own most top-voted answers on meta, they are all criticism about some feature, at varied degree of constructiveness. Meta loves rants, it would seem. And bandwagon-voting against badly implemented features.

Answer (score 13):

Take it from someone who's had some history (both good and bad) publicly answering questions on Meta from users who may feel some type of way about how their question was moderated on Stack Overflow main.

**Some rant questions on Meta *need* to be closed.**

I'm talking about the things that are obviously rant-worthy - someone decrying how unfriendly the site is, how unwelcoming we are for closing their obvious duplicate question, or how a downvote makes them feel oppressed somehow, and that we're obviously judging them based on us somehow knowing either their race or gender.

**However**, there exists a small subset of questions in which the OP presents themselves in a calm and rational fashion, and wants to discuss a matter of how something was moderated or change how something was actually moderated.  So long as the OP remains cool-headed and is discussing **the question at hand that they want to see revisited**, then we can usually facilitate a discussion.

About that "facilitate" part...

- **Y'all gotta stop posting discussions in comments. Full stop.**  If you want to answer the question, then *answer* the got-dang question.
- **Know when to fold 'em, when to hold 'em, when to walk away, and when to *run*.**  Some people will want to talk your ear off about the question or its moderation, and will insist on their way being right. There's a balancing act to be had here, and just talking isn't going to convince anyone about how the question shouldn't have been closed.
- **I won't disagree about downvotes on these kinds of questions.**  It's usually the case that the community can get a bit eager on downvoting a question that asks about this sort of thing...I wish something could be done about that.

---

In *this* case, the OP is dissatisfied that an answer of theirs was deleted by a diamond moderator, and that subsequent flags to get it undeleted were unsuccessful.  Turns out that [in solving the question they reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70302540/1079354),  [they posted a duplicate answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70302295/1079354).

Some things to note (as a typical hallmark of a rant-style question on Meta that probably *should* be closed):

- The OP omitted the fact that they posted the same answer to two questions.  Usually, hiding information is a bad start to a question like this.
- The OP wants their answer to "provide value", but...[given the context from the OP in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1673530/error-2003-hy000-cant-connect-to-mysql-server-on-127-0-0-1-111?answertab=votes#comment1546929_1673530), it's not unfair to automatically *assume* that the MySQL server and daemon are already installed on the machine.

Ultimately, this one is arguing over some moderation that definitely needed to happen.  In the context of what the person was complaining about, the answer didn't need to be added, and the answer wasn't adding much to the equation, so it made sense for it to be deleted.  It just so happened that a diamond mod came along and did it, making it unlikely that it'd be reversed.

Comment: "*Y'all gotta stop posting discussions in comments. Full stop. If you want to answer the question, then answer the got-dang question.*" this is an unworkable solution and one of the main points where meta *fundamentally* fails at its job. An answer is not a discussion. Discussion implies an ongoing thing or at the very least some exchange longer than two things, while Meta only allows for a question -> answer -> end.

Comment: @VLAZ: If you answer the question, you can then at least somewhat facilitate a conversation in comments, a little bit. At best you're limited to clarifications or remarks on your position, which is by design; you should avoid long sessions of discussion outside of chat as much as you can.

Comment: And this the failure of Meta. Specifically the discussion tag. There is no discussion that can happen with this approach.

Comment: Let's see... "In the context of what the person was complaining about, the answer didn't need to be added" – another context (which the proposed meta-answer addresses) (admittedly rare) would be someone in a similar situation, before posting an answer, looking for what to do *instead*, because obviously it's a bad idea to post duplicate answer. (more likely would be someone come across the meta question by chance, browsing new meta posts or something else) Questions are not just for the OP right? (or is it on meta?)

Comment: @VLAZ agreed that discussion is really hard. Group discussions, that is. It is still a ping pong system designed for one on one interactions. Group discussions tend to take the form of piling on really. But it's the best we got besides chat.

Comment: Is this reasoning consistent with your position on the [incident from 9 months ago](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/405681)? Because the asker back then did not really _"present themselves in a calm and rational fashion"_, yet you had voted to reopen the question.

Comment: @E_net4thecurator:  Yes.  [The original suggestion that was posed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/405582/1), while definitely coming across as a rant, could be turned into [something entirely constructive](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/405582/7) and could be something we could objectively disagree with.  ***Disagreeing*** with a proposal does not mean that the proposal should be ***closed***.  Those are two different and divergent things.  You don't close discussions you disagree with.

Comment: @E_net4thecurator:  Something else that also helped was that the OP remained engaged and level-headed in the conversations, didn't resort to *ad hominem* attacks and remained something that the still sought the community's input to.  A disagreeing perspective is still valid input.

Comment: _"the OP remained engaged and level-headed in the conversations, didn't resort to ad hominem attacks and remained something that the still sought the community's input to"_ Well no, I don't think the OP remained level-headed. As I am still well aware of verbiage originally employed in that question and still remember the inflammatory comments that user eventually posted there, I disagree with that assessment. I'm not the only one thinking the same way here either. What still confuses me greatly to this day is why we're all so divided on whether the question was constructive or not.